# echo value from multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My PHP call is storing a table from mySQL with the following code.

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmtMyCountTotals)) {
    $stmtMyCountTotalsrow = array(
        'IndividualUnitsCounted' => $IndividualUnitsCounted, 
        'IndividualUnitsAdjusted' => $IndividualUnitsAdjusted
    );

    $stmtMyCountTotalsrows[] = $stmtMyCountTotalsrow;
}

$stmtMyCountTotals->close();
```

I can not seem to pull a individual value from it. For Example If I want to pull a number from column 1 row 2. I know this is a basic question but I can not seem to find an answer.

Comment: Hello, where is you last question, about: `PHP to Insert Empty Months into foreach loop`, I have the solution.

Comment: I wanted to add more information. Deleted it by accident. I am going to repost as soon as stack will let me about 9 minutes.

Comment: nvm I undelete it. Still learning stack

Comment: The information is enough. Hope my answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multidimensional array, so you would access it like so:

```
$row1col2 = $stmtMyCountTotalsrows[1][2]
$row2col1 = $stmtMyCountTotalsrows[2][1]
```

But since it is associative you would want:

```
$var = $stmtMyCountTotalsrows[1]['IndividualUnitsCounted'];
```

If you want to access it by column, then you would need to retrieve the column names first into an array:

```
$cols = array_keys($stmtMyCountTotalsrows[0]);
$var = $stmtMyCountTotalsrows[1][$cols[1]]
//                                     ^ where this is the column number
```

Comment: His second dimension is an associative array, not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

There are no column numbers in your array, the second dimension is an associative array. So it should be:

```
$stmtMyCountTotalsrows[$row_number]['IndividualUnitsCounted']
$stmtMyCountTotalsrows[$row_number]['IndividualUnitsAdjusted']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array inside another array. Or a multidimensional array. It looks like this:

```
Array(
  0 => Array(
            'IndividualUnitsCounted' => 'Something',
            'IndividualUnitsAdjusted' => 'Something Else'
            ),
  1 => Array(
            'IndividualUnitsCounted' => 'Yet another something',
            'IndividualUnitsAdjusted' => 'Final something'
            ),
  ...
  ...
)
```

If this array is called `$stmtMyCountTotalsrows`:

`$stmtMyCountTotalsrows[0]['IndividualUnitsCounted']` returns "Something"
`$stmtMyCountTotalsrows[0]['IndividualUnitsCounted']` returns "Something Else"
`$stmtMyCountTotalsrows[1]['IndividualUnitsAdjusted']` returns "Yet another something"
`$stmtMyCountTotalsrows[1]['IndividualUnitsAdjusted']` returns "Final something"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the name of the columns beforehand, you could use `current()` for the first:

```
echo current($stmtMyCountTotalsrows[1]);
```

Alternatively, use `array_slice()`:

```
echo current(array_slice(stmtMyCountTotalsrows, 0, 1));
```